# How to use members of a structure for arithmetic operators (add,sub,mul,div a variable to a struct member)

Tags: c, math, struct

Sorry for the noob question. How do i use arith operators to variables within the structure?

I have this struct

```
struct account {
    int no;
    char name[100];
    int pin;
    float id;
};
```

what I want to do is add a value to float `id`

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <process.h>

main() {
    struct account {
        int no;
        char name[100];
        int pin;
        float id;
    }; 
    struct account rec;
    float i;
    printf("enter var value \n");
    scanf("%f", &i);

    printf("enter value to struct\n");
    scanf("%f", &rec.id);

    rec.id = rec.id + i;

    printf("sum is %0.2f", rec.id);
}
```

the value of `rec.id` stays the same.

I know I'm missing something. hopefully it wouldn't be too much of a bother

Comment: Please check the return values from `scanf` - they are important!

Comment: `rec.i` will throw an error. Do you mean just `i`? What is your input and output?

Comment: @ctx oh sorry about, yep just i

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format specifiers of `scanf()` differ from those of `printf()`. Especially the length of the decimals cannot be given there, so the flags `0.2` to `%f` are invalid. Just use

```
scanf("%f",&i);

printf("enter value to struct\n");
scanf("%f",&rec.id);
```

As Jonathan Leffler noted, it is however possible to specify the total length of the number (including dot and decimals), for example with `%4f` to scan for a four character decimal.

Furthermore, you should enable all compiler warnings and listen to them. You would have observed warnings, which show up this exact problem.

Additionally, you should check the return values of `scanf()` to see, if the conversions succeeded. Otherwise, the values in your variables remain uninitialized.

Two minor issues:

- Use `int main (void)`
- Explicitly return a value from `main()` or call `exit(0)` (not strictly needed anymore if you use at least the C99 standard)

Comment: You can use `%4f` with `scanf()` to specify that no more than 4 digits (or 3 digits plus decimal point, or sign and 2 digits and decimal point, etc) are to be converted.  You can't use `%0.2f` though, as you say.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding to my stupid question. :) 
i've realized too late that scanf has different specifiers. thanks again man